# Magento selected Attribute result

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I would like to add a Text depends on selected Attribute option: I create a Attribute with the optiones YES or NO.
I want to create with php if I select in the Admin Panel yes that if should start another php code (that will show a few text on the category pages)
But if I select No it should not run through the code, I mean don't display the text

Comment: the problem is if I add `code`if ($_product->getAttributeText(‘messagetimer’) == “Yes”){..the text php code}`code` mst features of the main disappear I don't know why

Comment: Please explain better the problem. Do you have to print an extra text for each product in the "product list" only if product attribute is "Yes"?

Comment: @Thundar yes only if product attribute is "Yes"  but I've already tried like ... <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText(‘texter’) == “Yes”): ?> the php code for the text here

<?php endif; ?> So basically if “texter” is set to YES then run the code and if set to no then display nothing

Comment: Did you enabled the attribute to be viewed in product list, in the backend?
Try: `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('messagetimer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)` instead of `$_product->getAttributeText(‘messagetimer’)`

Answer (score 1):

If you created a Yes/No attribute (select Yes/No for the Catalog Input Type field), then you can check the value simply using

```
$_product->getData('my_attribute_code');
```

This will return either `0` or `1`.

So if you try

```
if($_product->getData('my_attribute_code')){
    echo 'My text';
}
```

Note that depending on the context you may have to load the product first to get this value, so if nothing comes out of the getAttribute function, so you may have to execute this code before the previous one :

```
$_product->load($_product->getId())
```

And this should work.

**EDIT**: Note that this will not work if you create a dropdown attribute and set manually Yes and No as values. You need to chose Yes/No for the Catalog Input Type field of your attribute.

Cheers

Comment: In Yes/No attribute the data is not 0/1: it has a different couple of integer values (ie: 18/19). This are different for each attribute. You can find the right values in the source code of the select on the product edit page, or in database.

Comment: Yes/No product attributes in Magento are booleans. So they have 0/1 value. This can be verified in the `eav_attribute` table where you'll find `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean` as the source model for this kind of attributes.